# Abreviaturas de anuncios de periódico

Tags: coloquialismos, abreviaturas, argentina

Leyendo la sección de anuncios (sección "Servicios", y dentro de ella "Personas buscadas") de un periódico argentino he encontrado unas abreviaturas, de las cuales solo entiendo dos, "Sr" y "Sra" (Señor y Señora). ¿A qué se refieren las otras?

> Sra eleg dist bc Sr fs [*número de teléfono*]
>
> Sra sens f/s bca Sr [*número de teléfono*]

Comment: Parecen *'anuncios personales'*; pueden ser algo como:
`Señora elegante distinguida busca Señor fs(?)` 
`Señora sensual f/s(?) busca Señor`

Comment: Podrías dar más contexto a esta pregunta? Esas no parecen abreviaturas oficiales de la RAE, así que habrá que sacar su significado del contexto. Siguiendo con la idea de que son anuncios personales "sens" podría ser "sensible"

Comment: También puedes tomar una foto del anuncio y adicionarla a la pregunta. Eso puede dar más contexto.

Comment: Me sumo a @Diego y DGaleano en la petición de más datos. Sin contexto, esto puede querer decir mil cosas: _señora elegante y distinguida busca señor facineroso_, _señora elegida y distinta busca señor sin facsímil_...

Comment: El anuncio estaba en la sección "Servicios" y dentro de ella "Personas buscadas", y a la derecha de las frases hay números de teléfono

Comment: Puedes añadir algo más de otros anuncios? Viendo lo que otras personas ponen podemos deducir qué es habitual en esa sección y tratar de descifrar el "código" que estas personas están usando en este medio (porque ya intuimos que no son abreviaturas estándar). Ellos abrevian palabras de uso frecuente que están acostumbrados a ver en la sección y que los habituales de la misma entienden. Por ejemplo "sens" puede ser "sensible" o "sensual", f/s puede ser "fines de semana" (para verse los fines de semana)

Comment: Voto por cerrar la pregunta. Este no es un sitio de adivinanzas y esto no parece ser una duda sobre el lenguaje español.

Comment: @DGaleano, Supongo que sí es sobre el español, pero tienes toda la razón en que es off-topic formulada así. Al no ser abreviaturas oficiales, quién nos confirma que "sens" es "sensible" y no "sensual" o "sensacional"? Así formulada es cierto que la pregunta nos tiene jugando a detectives y por lo tanto es _too-broad_, ya que no podríamos comprobar la veracidad de las respuestas. Ojala el OP pusiese más información y contexto y facilitase respuestas que no son opiniones o suposiciones.